# Using emacs on a Mac. Option is not being recognized as the Meta key?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to use emacs on my MacBook Pro (2016). I was taught that Option/alt key works as the Meta key for emacs on a Mac. However, when I do M-g, for example, © gets printed onto the document I'm editing instead of the actual command being executed. This problem is observed with both the right and left  Option keys.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using emacs from your terminal, there is an option (Preferences...) that will allow you tu use `Option` key as `Meta` key. [Here's a link to a nice article explaining it it depth](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/01/use-option-as-meta-key-in-mac-os-x-terminal/).